# Check if string contains commas

Tags: php, string

Check if string contains commas in it?
i have a sting how can i check it it contains comma separated values or not

```
example : $search=6,7,8,9,10
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

php function `strpos` return position of string if it's not false or -1 then your string contain character.

```
$searchForValue = ',';
$stringValue = '115,251';

if( strpos($stringValue, $searchForValue) !== false ) {
     echo "Found";
}
```

Comment: i think this is best

Comment: raher than preg_math

Answer (score 0):

You can try with **preg_math** or **strpos** methods.

```
$re = '/,/m';
$str = 'Hi...1,2,3,4';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: `preg_match` is extremely slow compared to `strpos`.